# Build issue with Ivy and CASL

Tags: casl

I have tried install CASL for Angular in my project. Unfortunately, when I try to start the application, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in /Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@casl/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/dist/es6/index.js
Module build failed (from /Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: /Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@casl/angular/__ivy_ngcc__/dist/es6/index.js: Column must be greater than or equal to 0, got -21
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_findMapping [as _findMapping] (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:543:13)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_allGeneratedPositionsFor [as allGeneratedPositionsFor] (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:201:22)
    at /Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:186:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
    at buildMappingData (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:147:12)
    at mergeSourceMap (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/merge-map.js:21:17)
    at generateCode (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/generate.js:74:39)
    at run (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:55:33)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.transform (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:27:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/gensync/index.js:254:32)
    at /Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (/Users/julien/Documents/repositories/frontend/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:11)
```

I'm using the latest version of angular "10.0.9". If I disable completely the source maps then the message disappear but it's not really an option during development.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you tried to update angular in https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples/tree/master/packages/angular-todo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in @casl/angular with source maps generation which was fixed in @casl/angular@4.1.5

Now, it works as expected